# How to iterate when you don't know if your object will be iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sometimes I have multiple axes in `axes[0]`, and sometimes just one. So to iterate over it/them, I use the following:

`for ax,_x in [(axes[0], X[0])] if len(X)==1 else zip(axes[0],X):`

What is the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp

Comment: `hasattr(axes[0], "__iter__")` or `try/except`, maybe?

Comment: You don't need to check the length just use `zip(axes[0],X)` . But if your aim is creating the columns, when you are not aware of the length of iterables the best way is using `itertools.zip_longest()` (if you want to keep all the items from longer iterable) other wise just use `zip`.

Comment: A container of length 1 is still iterable.

Comment: @Kasramvd I get an error when I do naive zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the best way is to just iterate. [Don't ask for permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) (with `if` checks, rather wrap it in a `try-except` block for handling the "forgiveness" cases.

As others have commented though, you shouldn't create different cases if `X` is a list of size `1`, that still is iterable. If you use `zip` it will stop at the shortest iterable:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]    
>>> y = [1, 2]

>>> list(zip(l, y))
[(1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

If you need to work with all values of the longer iterable and provide defaults for the missing values of the shorted one, use `zip_longest` from itertools with an appropriate `fillvalue`:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest

>>> list(zip_longest(l, y, fillvalue=0))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0)]
```